# Finding all words that differ by one letter

Tags: regex, perl, file

I’m working on a word chain program, and given two words and a file of words the program finds how to go from one word to the other by only changing one letter at a time, changing to one word from another based off of the words in the file.

I’m working on a subroutine that will return a list of words from the file that are only different by one letter.

I know I’d probably use regular expressions to find the words and add it to a list. Thanks for any help someone can give.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$start_word = $ARGV[0];
$end_word = $ARGV[1];

my $file = "wordlist.txt";

open (FH, "< $file" ) or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";
my @lines;
while(<FH>)
{
        push (@lines, $_);
}

#print @lines;

#find word diff

#return list of words with 1 letter diff

#recursion to return smallest stack
```

Comment: How are the *given two words* used in the algorithm?

Comment: Sorry , I clarified my original post with an edit.

Comment: So let's see the program...

Comment: Are `abcd`  and `acd` ***different by one letter***?

Comment: No, for this they have to be the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy optimization to thin your pool of candidates: all possible words in the chain must have the same length.

```
sub read_all_candidates {
  my($dict,$start) = @_;

  open my $fh, "<", $dict or die "$0: open $dict: $!\n";

  my @pool;
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    next if length($_) != length($start) || $_ eq $start;
    push @pool, lc $_;
  }

  \@pool;
}
```

Given the length of words in your chain, you can also construct a specialized `Regexp` instance for words of that length.

```
# Computes and caches a Regexp object (created with qr//) that
# matches pairs of one-hop words concatenated one after the
# other (e.g., "doghog" for dog and hog). For example, words of
# length 3 would generate the following pattern:
#
#   ^(.)(.)(.)(?:.\2\3|\1.\3|\1\2.)$
#
# You need only call this sub once per run.
my $_one_hopper;
sub _compute_one_hopper {
  my($length) = @_;

  my $pattern = "^" . "(.)" x $length;

  my @choices;
  foreach my $n (1 .. $length) {
    push @choices => join "", map $_ == $n ? "." : "\\$_", 1 .. $length;
  }

  #print $pattern, "\n";
  $pattern .= "(?:" . join("|" => @choices) . ")\$";

  eval "\$_one_hopper = qr/$pattern/" or die "$0: internal error";
}
```

Use `$_one_hopper` as in

```
# Returns one-hop neighbors of $from taken from @$words but that are
# not present in %$seen.
sub one_hop {
  my($from,$words,$seen) = @_;

  $_one_hopper = _compute_one_hopper length $from
    unless defined $_one_hopper;

  grep !$seen->{$_} && "$from$_" =~ /$_one_hopper/, @$words;
}
```

Tying it all together, your main loop has the following structure.

```
my $words = read_all_candidates $dict, $start;

my $min  = 1;         # minimum number of transitions from $start to
my $seen = {};        # words seen in earlier batches (prevents
my @last = ($start);  # last batch of neighbors

while (@last) {
  my @next;
  foreach my $word (@last) {
    my @onemore = one_hop $word, $words, $seen;
    ++$seen->{$_} for @onemore;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm working through your solution slowly but surly.

Comment: @Greg Bacon "... all possible words in the chain must have the same length." This is not right. A word could also have one letter more or one letter less. Example: word = words

Comment: @AlexanderBalzer OP [commented on the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453872/finding-all-words-that-differ-by-one-letter/33454461#comment54695798_33453872) to state that the words must have the same length.